# only one ajax call from javascript loop instead of looping multiple ajax calls

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, for-loop

I have a 2D array in javascript.

Currently I am running a for loop and in each loop I make a ajax call to update the db.

I know this is not good form and am looking at a way to update the db from the loop with only one ajax call.

I know I have to pass the array to the ajax page and upadate in one go but for the life of me I cannot figure out where to start with this

any help greatly appreciated

heres my javascript for loop

```
for(var m=0; m<array.length; m++){
$.post("update_page_positions.php",{page_ref:array[m][0], ref:array[m][12], menu_pos:array[m][1], sub_menu_pos:array[m][2], top_menu:array[m][3], pagelink:array[m][4], indexpage:array[m][5], hidden:array[m][6], page_title:array[m][7], page_desc:array[m][8], page_keywords:array[m][9], page_name:array[m][10], deletedpage:array[m][11]},         
    function(data,status){             
});
```

heres my ajax php code

```
<?
include("connect.php");     
$ref = $_POST['ref'];
$page_ref = $_POST['page_ref'];
$menu_pos = $_POST['menu_pos'];
$sub_menu_pos = $_POST['sub_menu_pos'];  
$top_menu = $_POST['top_menu'];
$indexpage = $_POST['indexpage'];       
$page_name = $_POST['page_name'];    
$page_title = $_POST['page_title'];
$page_desc = $_POST['page_desc'];   
$page_keywords = $_POST['page_keywords'];   
$hidden = $_POST['hidden']; 
$pagelink = $_POST['pagelink']; 
$deletedpage = $_POST['deletedpage'];   

mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET menu_pos='$menu_pos', sub_menu_pos='$sub_menu_pos', top_menu='$top_menu', indexpage='$indexpage', page_name='$page_name', page_title='$page_title', desc1='$page_desc', keywords_list='$page_keywords', hidden='$hidden', link='$pagelink' WHERE ref='$ref' AND page_ref='$page_ref'")

?>
```

Comment: Do you know something about calback in javascript. Use that.
It'll be useful when you are waiting for response from ajax call.
You can use $ajax's async feature.
return something from PHP-end so that you will be sure of query status.

Comment: the ajax works fine, I just dont want to make an ajax call everytime I go through the loop as the loop can hold many elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS-Call:

```
$.post('update_page_positions.php', 
    {'myArray': m},
    function(data, statusText) {
        // This block is optional, fires when the ajax call is complete
    }
);
```

AJAX-Handler:

```
<?php

include("connect.php");     
$myArray = json_decode($_POST['myArray']);

// do stuff with $myArray here.

?>
```

Comment: how do I see the structure on the php side to push the array variables into strings for insertion in mysql db

Answer (score 0):

Just post whole array like this:

$.post("update_page_positions.php",{"your_array":array} //...

then in PHP refer to this variable: $_POST['your_array'], it will be array aswell

```
var_dump($_POST['your_array']);
```

this will help you see its structure and use it further.

Comment: what is the full line of code for the post statement $.post("update_page_positions.php",{"your_array":array} //...

Comment: $.post("update_page_positions.php",{"your_array":array},function(data,status){             
});

Comment: but how do I see the'var_dump' so I can see the structure as its in a ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with all the objects :

```
var data = [];

for(var m=0; m<array.length; m++){
    var obj = {page_ref      : array[m][0], 
               menu_pos      : array[m][1], 
               sub_menu_pos  : array[m][2], 
               top_menu      : array[m][3], 
               pagelink      : array[m][4], 
               indexpage     : array[m][5], 
               hidden        : array[m][6], 
               page_title    : array[m][7], 
               page_desc     : array[m][8], 
               page_keywords : array[m][9], 
               page_name     : array[m][10], 
               deletedpage   : array[m][11],
               ref           : array[m][12] 
              };
    data.push(obj)
});

$.post("update_page_positions.php", data);
```

Do the iterating on the serverside:

```
<?php

foreach( $_POST as $P ) {
    include("connect.php");     
    $ref           = $P['ref'];
    $page_ref      = $P['page_ref'];
    $menu_pos      = $P['menu_pos'];
    $sub_menu_pos  = $P['sub_menu_pos'];  
    $top_menu      = $P['top_menu'];
    $indexpage     = $P['indexpage'];       
    $page_name     = $P['page_name'];    
    $page_title    = $P['page_title'];
    $page_desc     = $P['page_desc'];   
    $page_keywords = $P['page_keywords'];   
    $hidden        = $P['hidden']; 
    $pagelink      = $P['pagelink']; 
    $deletedpage   = $P['deletedpage'];   

    mysql_query("UPDATE pages ......")
}

?>
```